# Learning Finance with Mathematica

Tags: reference-request, finance

### Background

My math background is strong by CS standards, probably normal by mathematica standards. (i.e. familiarity with real analysis, linear algebra, managed to read the proof of the prime number theorem :-) )

The goal here is NOT to start a hedge fund of sorts; it's mainly to pick up the basics of financial / stock market background (but it's much more fun when I'm playing with real data / writing programs rather than just reading a textbook.)

I want to play around with learning the basics of finance (and writing some serious code in Mathematica).

Ideally, I want to "learn by doing" -- i.e. rather than just read textbook formulas, I would like to:

- play with real world stock data
- implement the various definitions / algorithms / functions and see how they work

Looking around, the best I have found is this book:

Computational Financial Mathematics using MATHEMATICA®: Optimal Trading in Stocks and Options

Seems like the most highly recommended

However, since I'm clueless, I would like to get some feedback (and suggestions for other resources to use for learning.)

Thanks!

Comment: Just a warning: book recomendations are a tuchy subject on the SE family of sites. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations). There was however already a book recommendation on mma.se that didn't get closed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/what-mathematica-book-to-buy), so perhaps this are a bit more relaxed here:)

Comment: @Ajasja: Is there a way I can modify the syntax of my post to avoid it being closed?

Comment: I would just wait and see if somebody has a problem with this Q. Personally I'm not against book recommendations, since good books don't change that much in *Mathematica* world.

Comment: There is also [Modelling Financial Derivatives with MATHEMATICA](http://www.amazon.com/Modelling-Financial-Derivatives-MATHEMATICA-William/dp/052159233X/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top) by William Shaw. I don't know anything about the book, but the author is knowledgable in Mathematica (AFAIK), so it may be of some value if you want to look at it from the Mathematica side. It is ridiculously expensive new, but used copies could be (marginally) affordable.

Comment: Mathematica books are very weird -- in that most of the authors are these highly qualified PhDs that either (1) come from wolfram research or (2) were former academic researchers.

Comment: Srdjan Stojanovic's book, Computational Financial Mathematics using MATHEMATICA, is top notch.

Comment: I recommend MathEstate.com, just brilliant.  Its authors know Mathematica very well and have more original insights into finance than anything you'll find in conventional financial engineering.  As for books its hard to find anything on financial engineering that doesn't start and end with unfounded assumptions whether the authors know Mathematica or not.  So I think you should stick with basics.  Taleb's "Dynamic Hedging" - comprehensive, his best book by far.  Mandelbrot's, "(Mis)behavior of Markets"  A. Brown's "Poker Face of Wall Street" & "Red Blooded Risk".  Thorp's "Beat the Market".

Comment: Just a follow up, How could I forget, John Kelly's seminal 1956 paper "A New Interpretation of Information Rate" indispensable, and amazing how so few in financial engineering have ever heard of it.  Thorp, who invented Black Scholes long before the Black and Scholes did and developed Delta hedging, arguably the 1st quantitative approach relied heavily on Kelly as do PIMCO, Brown, and most frequentist oriented quantitative strategies.

Comment: I think the real issue you will have is finding something that is up to date with Mathematica in this area. 

Mathematica added a large number of functions for financial engineering in version 8, so I don't think there are any up to date books on this.

Comment: @Searke is right, a lot of finance functionality is getting added, including recent release of Financial Platform and Bloomberg Link capability. Do you know about videos and downloadable notebooks here? http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-finance-platform-2012/  Please note `CUDAFinancialDerivative` in "HPC in Finance" talk. I am sure all this new stuff is not in any books. Wolfram Training site is a good sources for up-to-date info: http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/finance/ Let me know if you want me to post more info like this as an answer.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov : Edited question to make it general. Answer away. :-)

Comment: Define "basics of finance". That can be anything. Stocks? Currencies? Bonds? Commodities? Futures? Options? Credit derivatives? International? Historical data analysis? Data research? Real-time Trading? There's some finance programs in the US where you only learn accounting, and they call "financial math" what we would call "simple arithmetic". Define "financial / stock market background". That involves micro-economics and macro-economics. Your question is very vague. I can, however, recommend both books mentioned here, they're very good, although they're getting old (both are pre-4.2).

Comment: It might be worth reading some of the stuff Michael Kelly has written and presented over the years (search in Wolfram Library). Michael has been both a math academic and an iBank quant where he has priced options and written HFT algorithms. He is now a consultant to WRI and has had a large part to do with the finance platform.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I own a copy of [Modelling Financial Derivatives with Mathematica](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052159233X) by William Shaw. I think it was a ground-breaking book for its time. However, here are some issues you should be aware of:

- It was published in 1998 and is based on Mathematica version *3*. We are now at 8, anticipating 9. Much of the graphics code he uses is now obsolete (eg `` Graphics`Graphics ``).
- Much of the functionality he builds in the book is now built-in to Mathematica itself. See [the list of functions here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialDerivative.html).

Chapter 3 is a nice intro to the mathematical preliminaries of derivatives, but there will be better ones in more recent introductory texts that are not specific to Mathematica.

My general concern about both Shaw's book and the subsequent Mathematica implementations of these pricing algorithms is that they are, in the end as far as I can tell, based on an assumption of Gaussian noise in the differential equation defining the pricing equation. This is still the standard approach in many workplaces, but especially since the crisis, the deviation of reality from Gaussian-based models has generated some disquiet in the profession. (This has been directed more at Gaussian copulas than the underlying Black-Scholes model, but it is possible that the industry is going to start moving off in another direction away from the standard methods encapsulated in the Mathematica functionality.) I am not close enough to the recent literature on financial engineering specifically to know exactly how this is playing out yet.

I do not own the book by Stojanovic you referenced in your question but looking at the contents pages online, I do not see anything there that is not now included directly in Mathematica with version 8. Again, this book came out in 2002, so it predates Mathematica's finance functionality as well as its dynamic functionality (`Manipulate` and friends). And again, it is all based on Black-Scholes and Gaussian noise and doesn't go beyond that to include consideration of fat-tailed innovations. (NB: this is something that Mathestate.com, mentioned in comments, gets *right* - there is lots of discussion of Levy-stable and other heavy-tailed distributions. So perhaps you are better off starting there than with a book.)

I think you will be better off getting a *recent* book on financial engineering and pricing, and practice implementing things in Mathematica from there, bearing in mind how much is already built in. I particularly admire [Janet M Tavakoli](http://www.amazon.com/Janet-M.-Tavakoli/e/B001IQXGUQ/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_pop_1) on structured finance.

To summarise, I don't think there is currently a good book on financial engineering that addresses Mathematica's current functionality, but I would be delighted to be proven wrong. Perhaps this is a market niche for someone.

One place you might want to consider for thoughts and ideas is the "Cutting Edge" column in *Risk* magazine. That stuff is pretty advanced, but it gives you a sense of where practitioners, rather than academics, are going. Also have a look at the sister SE for [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/), but note that software questions are offtopic there, at least last time I looked.

Comment: Is Gaussian still assumed? A lot of the papers I've read in quantitative finance use either Student-t or Cauchy or power-law distributions — basically, anything that has a fat tail and these were all from between 2000-now

Comment: @R.M they are assumed in the two books referenced - certainly Shaw and as far as I can tell, Stojanovic. My impression (and I am not working in an investment bank) is that many shops still just go with the Gaussian. The VaR built into Basel II pretty much assumes it too.

Comment: Heh, everybody loves Gaussian... until it goes wrong :)

Comment: Fyi, also check the piece in Wired on the failure of Li's copula-based correlation model - called something like "The formula that brought down Wall Street" (hyperbolic title of course - no single model is to blame and models don't make decision, fund managers do).

Comment: Fyi, also recommend the nontechnical books by Taleb, especially *Fooled by Randomness*

Comment: I've been reading WSJ and the NYT for over a decade - real world is a lot more complicated than any model or algorithm, so beware

Comment: Also be aware that a many if not most or even all time-series econometric models - regardless of sophistication - attempt to predict the future based on curve fitting the past. But if there are no symmetries the inference is not logically justified.

Comment: Is my answer/outline going in a direction that seems useful to you?  I'll do my best to follow Leonid's suggestion to emphasize the use of Mathematica.

Answer (score 33):

Most of the financial modeling/Mathematica books I've seen are intended to (1) provide theorical insights and Mathematica based tools to price "exotic" derivatives, and/or (2) to show how to use Mathematica to develop derivative trading strategies. Very helpful for experienced quants. Not the best way to learn about investing.

Successful investing requires the skillful combination of five aspects of finance. You should know how: 1) financial markets work, 2) different financial instruments are priced, 3) assets can be combined in a portfolio to meet a particular investment objective, 4) risk is measured and and managed, and 5) investment success is measured and monitored. Each of these five areas require practical knowledge and also involve important theoretical questions. (In spite of the fact that two Nobel prices have been awarded for work in categories 2 and 3, research is ongoing in each of the five areas). Mathematica is a useful tool for the student and practitioner in each area.

Although Mathematica has sophisticated functions for valuing various instruments, if you want to learn about finance, it's better to write your own financial functions so you know how pricing works.

### 1. PRICING FINANCIAL INSTRUMENTS (What's it worth?)

Bonds are a great place to start learning about finance. The price of a treasury bond is just the sum of the present values of each of its coupon payments and its principal at maturity. Moreover, this "sum of the present value of future cashflows,"  introduces a foundational concept of finance called [the law of one price](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_pricing). The law of one prices says everything that has the same future cash flows MUST have the same price (or the differences will be arbitraged away). Therefore, any package of financial instruments that has the same future cashflows as a certain bond must have the same price as that bond.

Mathematica makes it relatively easy to learn about bond pricing and the surprisingly many and more subtle related concepts of duration, curvature, yield to maturity, etc.

#### 1a. Fixed Income Securities

The present value of a future cash payment is equal to:

```
presentValue = cashPayment/(1 + annualInterestRate)^(timeInYearsToPayment)
```

This means that, if you know the face value, coupon payments, and time to maturity of a bond that won't default (you can be sure the payment will really happen), you can calculate it's price in any environment (meaning when bonds are trading at any particular yield).  For example:

**Treasury Bonds (which, in theory, will never default)**

The price of a US Treasury bond is:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, Treasury bonds are really mathematical entities. And you can learn about them with Mathematica by making and playing with models. For example, bond prices are a simple but interesting function of yield:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This price-yield curve is the essential element of bond pricing. The curve itself a function of bond maturity, coupon, coupon frequency, and yield. Its slope (called bond duration) is a measure of the bond's sensitivity to interest rate changes, and since the curve isn't flat, duration is also a function of interest rates (curvature). This gets complicated, but bonds are managed in terms of duration and curvature.

*The Yield Curve*

Bonds are actually priced from a [yield curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_curve), either the Treasury yield curve, or one based on treasuries but adjusted with yields appropriate to a specific bond.  Two yield curves are shown below. The blue curve corresponds to Treasury yields on Dec, 17, 2012. The present value of each coupon payment and of the bond's value at maturity is based on the interest rate for that payment's maturity taken from the current yield curve.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note how different they are.  The same bond would have a very different price when priced against those two curves. Let's calculate the price of a bond relative to the blue curve. The values use for the yield curve are based on a standard set of Treasuries with maturities of one month, three months, six months, one year, etc. We need a interpolation function to get the interest rate for any maturity.  Let's assume a 10 year bond with a 4% coupon paid once a year.  The price for a 100$ bond is 120.69%.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The bond has a price of 109.12$ against the higher yield curve. As shown in the price-yield curve above, bond prices fall when yields rise. The yield curve changes over time. Let's use Wolfram|Alpha to compare the yield curves for [October 15, 2012](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=yield+curve+October+15%2C+2012) and [October 15, 2005](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=yield+curve+October+15%2C+2005). What would happen to our bond's price under those changes?

*Wolfram|Alpha Bond Queries*
[Bond Price](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bond+price)
[Duration](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bond+duration)
[Modified Duration](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bond+duration&a=*FS-_**BondDuration.D-.*BondDuration.rc-.*BondDuration.y--&f2=11+Mar+2013&f=BondDuration.SD_11+Mar+2013&f3=20+Oct+2017&f=BondDuration.MD_20+Oct+2017&f4=5+%25&f=BondDuration.y_5+%25&f5=7+%25&f=BondDuration.rc_7+%25&a=*FP.BondDuration.f-_SemiAnnual&a=*FVarOpt-_**BondDuration.DMOD--&a=*FVarOpt.2-_**-.***BondDuration.DCC---.**BondDuration.D---)
[Yield to Maturity](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=yield+to+maturity&lk=4&num=1)

*Bond Related Demonstrations*
[Price-Yield Curve](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PriceYieldCurve/)
[Maculay Duration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MacaulayDuration/)
[Macaulay Duration as the Balancing Point of a Seesaw](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MacaulayDurationAsTheBalancingPointOfASeesaw/)
[Valuation and Management of Bonds](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ValuationAndManagementOfBonds/)
[Yield, Spot, and Forward Curves](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/YieldSpotAndForwardCurves/)
[Term Structure of Interest Rates](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TermStructureOfInterestRates/)

*Mathematica Functions*
[FinancialBond](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialBond.html)

**Corporate Bonds (where default is possible)**

...

*Demonstrations*
[Credit Risk](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CreditRisk/)
[Transition Matrix](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TransitionMatricesOfMarkovChains/)

*Relevant Links*
[Yield Curves with Mathematica 6.0](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6956/YieldCurves.nb?file_id=6414)

**Callable Bonds (where future payments are contingent)**

**Pass-through Bonds (packages of various interest paying securities)**

**Miscellaneous Notes & Links**

[Bond Market Pricing Conventions](http://www.nasdaq.com/investing/bond-market-pricing-conventions.stm)
[Using Mathematica at BondDesk Group LLC](http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/12/17/going-inside-the-interface-with-mathematica/)
[Interest Rate Senstivity of Bonds](http://books.google.com/books?id=BkDxC_O1WisC&pg=PA561&lpg=PA561&dq=mathematica+bonds&source=bl&ots=hjjUGjHxAZ&sig=mZOW6UwmmzuqE-lRgROG42W2c28&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vc59UNXQDaWD0QH2i4H4Bg&ved=0CGEQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=mathematica%20bonds&f=false)

### 1b. Stocks

I'm going to replace this with a *Mathematica* centric discussion soon.  I'm gathering my thoughts a the moment...

(The classical approach to valuing stocks is to use a dividend discount model. The underlying idea is that the present value of a stock is equal to the sum of the present values of it's future dividends. This approach, along with various implementation issues is discussed throughly by [Aswath Damodaran](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/adamodar/New_Home_Page/dam2ed.htm), a professor at NYU. There are lots of issues: how do you estimate the size of the uncertain future cashflows, how much should they be "discounted", and more recently, does this approach give the proper importance to sentiment. For example, [John Cochrane](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/research/papers/discount_rates_jf.pdf), the past President of the American Financial Institution and a professor at the University of Chicago, has argued that "price-dividend ratios correspond to discount-rate variations instead of variations in expected cash flows." He present evidence taken from many asset classes to support the generality of this claim. He suggest that the emphasis on future cash flows is misdirected. This fits into the broad category of behavioral investment theory.

Continuing in this theme, Philip Maymin (above) is the founding editor of [Algorithmic Finance](http://algorithmicfinance.org/), the current issue of which contains an [article](http://iospress.metapress.com/content/w1456212n3375225/fulltext.html), which claims that "The sentiment indicator we introduce gives a way to actually quantify the impact of human biases and sentiments directly on the markets instead of simply postulating effects which is often done in the field of Behavioral Finance. There are really a lot of open issues in what might seem to be a plain vanilla topic as stock pricing, and it is worth learning about them.  I've left out the Capital Asset Pricing Model, Arbitrage Pricing, and other subjects that are exciting, controversial, and fun to learn about.)

*Demonstrations*
[Expected Returns](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ExpectedReturnsOfTheDowIndustrialsFamaFrenchModel/)
[Return Distributions](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ModelingReturnDistributions/)

*Wolfram Videos*
[Financial Statistics](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=98&video=1013) (How to, using stock prices from W|A - Good)

*Related Internet Sites*
[Math Estate: Stock Investment Tools](http://www.mathestate.com/tools/Financial/map/Overview.html)

### 1c. Derivatives

**Forwards and Futures**

**Options**

**Swaps**

### 1d. "Alternative" Asset Classes

**Real Estate**

*Links*
[Math Estate: Real Estate Tools](http://www.mathestate.com/tools/Real%20Estate/real_estate.html)

**Commodities**

### 2. PORTFOLIOS (How do I package stocks, bonds, etc. together?)

*Demonstrations*
[Portfolio Simulation](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RandomSimulationOfAFinancialPortfolio/)
[Asset Allocation](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AssetAllocation/)
[Portfolio Analysis](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/UsingTensorsToAnalyzeALargePortfolioOfStocks/)
[Benefits of Diversification](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PortfolioDiversificationBenefitFromSubadditiveVaR/)

### 3. RISK MEASURMENT AND MANAGEMENT (What can go wrong?)

*Demonstrations*
[Value at Risk](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ValueAtRisk/)
[Value at Risk Explained](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AttributingPortfolioValueAtRiskRelationsWithComponentVaRMarg/)
[Bootstrapping to Compute Value-at-Risk Standard Errors](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BootstrappingToComputeValueAtRiskStandardErrors/)

*Links*
[Value at Risk](http://simonbenninga.com/wiener/MiER74.pdf)

### 4. PERFORMANCE EVALUATION (How am I doing?)

### 5. FINANCIAL MARKETS (What can I expect?)

### 6. Miscellaneous Items

[Risk and Return to Investments in Five Emerging Nations](http://omicsgroup.org/journals/2168-9458/2168-9458-1-102.pdf)
[Quantitative Research and Trading](http://jonathankinlay.com/)

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe The `Why` is critical to this whole enterprise. Someone with a strong Statistics, Econometrics and programming background will not go very far if they don't understand the Finance and Economics behind the models. Your road-map is absolutely essential to keep OP's project from being DOA. Presumably some of those MMA for Fin-engineering books will provide some of this perspective but I am not optimistic about the quality.

Comment: Hi George, [here's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38488/optimization-of-a-portfolio-of-stocks) a question about portfolio analysis that you perhaps could add to your list.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The answer to this question is a centerpiece of contemporary financial thinking. Both answers are very nice, but yours does a better job of displaying the risk-return trade-off. Very nice!  Add a utility function, and you've got modern finance (as you know). I've been meaning to get back to my list for a while. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm still pleased about having organized the list into the - What's it worth? How do I package stocks, bonds, etc. together? What can go wrong? How am I doing? What can I expect? - framework. So many textbooks on mathematical finance focus on things like valuing complex options, etc. and fail to help n ordinary reader learn how to use these nice tools to invest (IMO).

Comment: Hi George -- Can you suggest any references to MMA implementations for Pricing Bermuda Swaptions (for interest rate swaps in my case)?  I've started developing code for this, but my process and code would greatly benefit from seeing what others have done before me.  See my earlier question [MATLAB to Mathematica CorrelationMatrix implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167183/matlab-to-mathematica-correlationmatrix-implementation).

Answer (score 15):

I just wrote a book on financial engineering that uses Mathematica heavily. The publisher (World Scientific) says it should be available for purchase within a week or two. I have taught risk management and asset pricing and derivatives with these materials for the past few years at NYU-Poly. The point of the book is precisely to do lots of projects, the learn-by-doing approach you want. Here's more info: http://financialhacking.com

Comment: What assumptions does your book make -- Gaussian noise?

Answer (score 9):

Here are some links I collected in my answer to the post [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/66). The first link exposes quite well the new functionalities of Mathematica in this field.

**Finance** (some CUDA examples also)

- http://www.wolfram.com/events/chicago2011/nVidiaFinancePresentation.nb
- [High-Performance Computing in Finance](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/fin014.html)
- http://blog.wolfram.com/category/finance/
- [How can you compute Itō Integrals with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3141/66)

I agree with Verbeia when she recommends to learn by doing, this is a path I followed and it still pays off. The step by step discovery style of programming in a notebook where you can mix instructions, intermediate results and graphics (plus all the built-in functions like Interpolate or NExpectation) makes it easier to develop new stuff compared to other languages. When you see that something works you copy all important instructions and pack them in a function.

Answer (score 4):

With regards to 'Learning Finance with Mathematica', one of the best sites I've seen is

http://www.mathestate.com/.

It has two focuses; real estate and the financial market. The financial market end is very instructional and contains demo mathematica code as well as free downloadable code. It focuses on a number of market concepts, namely: risk, trends, market behavior, etc. I have used some of the downloadable code to understand market behavior during political events.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how deep you want to go into the details of  financial engineering (Multi Factor Models, Complicated Deal Types, ...) - if you intend to work with these things check out the Mathematica based solutions here

http://www.unrisk.com/index.php/products

Also some white papers on the underlying mathematical methods are available there

Comment: Can I calculate within FinancialData properties these as follows:

1. Earnings Yield = EBIT/Enterprise value 
..where Enterprise value is the sum of market value of equity (including preferred equity) and net interest bearing debt

2. Return of Investment (or Capital) =  EBIT/ Net Fixed Assets + Working Capital

???