# Problem with `NMinimize`

Tags: mathematical-optimization, finance

I wrote a code inspired by Rod's answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38488/optimization-of-a-portfolio-of-stocks) question. It is supposed to find the minimum variance portfolio of stocks and allows for arbitrary constraints on the weights of each stock:

```
optP[expR_,sd_,corr_,reqR_:0,cons_:0]:=Module[{pvar,wtsV,MV,pret,weights},
wtsV=Subscript[w,#]&/@Range[Length[expR]];
pret:=Sum[wtsV[[i]]*expR[[i]],{i,1,Length[expR]}];
pvar:=Sum[wtsV[[i]]*wtsV[[j]]*sd[[i]]*sd[[j]]*corr[[i]][[j]],{i,1,Length[expR]},{j,1,Length[expR]}];
If[cons==0,
    If[reqR==0,
    MV=NMinimize[{pvar,Total[wtsV]==1},wtsV],
    MV=NMinimize[{pvar,Total[wtsV]==1&&pret==reqR},wtsV]],
    If[reqR==0,
    MV=NMinimize[{pvar,Total[wtsV]==1&&(And@@(cons[[Position[wtsV,#][[1,1]]]][[1]]<=#<=cons[[Position[wtsV,#][[1,1]]]][[2]]&/@wtsV))},wtsV],
    MV=NMinimize[{pvar,Total[wtsV]==1&&pret==reqR&&(And@@(cons[[Position[wtsV,#][[1,1]]]][[1]]<=#<=cons[[Position[wtsV,#][[1,1]]]][[2]]&/@wtsV))},wtsV]]
];
Print[MV];
weights = wtsV /. MV[[2]];
Print["Expected return is"];
Print[Sum[weights[[i]]*expR[[i]], {i, 1, Length[weights]}]];
Print["Expected standard deviation is"];
Print[Sqrt[First[MV]]];
]
```

`expR` is a list containing expected returns, `sd` a list containing expected standard deviations, `corr` is the correlation matrix,`reqR` the required return and `cons` the constraints on the weights of individual stocks. `wtsV` is then the vector containing weights of each stock and `pret` and `pvar` are the portfolio return and variance, respectively. Now, if the weights are not restricted, i.e. one can short any stock(s), everything works well. But if I use constraints on the weights, the code returns unevaluated, i.e. only e.g. `MV$10261` appears (for the `Print[MV]` line of code) along with the corresponding unevaluated expected return and standard deviation. If I run the code step by step outside the `optP` function, it seems to work. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: the `MV$10261` is indicating `MV` was never assigned in the module. Hard to say more without seeing the input.

Comment: note if `cons` is a list then `cons==0` is neither true nor false and neither expression inside the `If` block is evaluated.  You might want that to be `If[TrueQ[cons==0]  , .. `

Comment: @george2079 You are right, changing the condition to `TrueQ[cons==0]` solved the problem. However, I thought that the two were equivalent...?

Comment: `Equal` can return `True` or `False` or remain unevaluated. If you do for example `{0}==0` it remains unevaluated. Wrapping in `TrueQ` forces any undetermined case to be `False` (more like you'd expect in a traditional language)