# Still having trouble evaluating expressions (involving Log this time)

Tags: evaluation, logarithmic-scale

I'm trying to get some old Mathematica code working on MMA 12.  I found the code at this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38488/optimization-of-a-portfolio-of-stocks/38713#38713).
Here's the relevant code:

```
Portfolio = {"AAPL", "BA", "IBM", "BMW.DE", "DIS", "R", "PEP", "BRBY.L", "AXP", "BTI"};
data = FinancialData[#, "Price", {{2016}, {2020}, "Month"}]["Path"][[All, 2]] & /@ Portfolio;
ListLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
Returns = Differences[Log[data[[#]]]] & /@ Range[10];
ListLinePlot[Returns, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

The second plot is empty.  When I look at **Returns**, it has this mess:

> {{Log[Quantity[24.172500610351562, "USDollars"]] -
> Log[Quantity[24.334999084472656, "USDollars"]],
> -Log[Quantity[24.172500610351562, "USDollars"]] + Log[Quantity[27.247499465942383, "USDollars"]],
> Log[Quantity[23.434999465942383, "USDollars"]] -
> Log[Quantity[27.247499465942383, "USDollars"]],
> -Log[Quantity[23.434999465942383, "USDollars"]] + Log[Quantity[24.96500015258789, "USDollars"]],
> Log[Quantity[23.899999618530273, "USDollars"]] -
> Log[Quantity[24.96500015258789, "USDollars"]],
> -Log[Quantity[23.899999618530273, "USDollars"]] + Log[Quantity[26.052499771118164, "USDollars"]],
> -Log[Quantity[26.052499771118164, "USDollars"]] + Log[Quantity[26.524999618530273, "USDollars"]],
> -Log[Quantity[26.524999618530273, "USDollars"]] + Log[Quantity[28.262500762939453, "USDollars"]],
> -Log[Quantity[28.262500762939453, "USDollars"]] + Log[Quantity[28.385000228881836, "USDollars"]],
> Log[Quantity[27.6299991607666, "USDollars"]] -
> Log[Quantity[28.385000228881836, "USDollars"]],
> -Log[Quantity[27.6299991607666, "USDollars"]] + Log[Quantity[28.954999923706055, "USDollars"]],
> -Log[Quantity[28.954999923706055, "USDollars"]] + Log[Quantity[30.337499618530273, "USDollars"]],

Theoretically, this is correct, but I want MMA to evaluate these expressions and plot the answer.  If I remove the **Log** function in the formula for the **Returns**, I get the expected results, but not on a logarithmic scale.

What is wrong with the **Returns** formula?  Why won't this version evaluate and plot?

Comment: Use `Log @ Ratios[data[[#]]]` instead of `Differences[Log[data[[#]]]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'QuantityMagnitude' function

```
Returns = 
  Differences[Log[QuantityMagnitude[data[[#]]]]] & /@ Range[10];
```

It produces valid figure on my computer (MMA 12.0)

Answer (score 0):

When using old code for `FinancialData`, the `Method->"Legacy"` option solves most of the problems with the [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38713/41569) you mentioned. Add the legacy option to `FinancialData` wherever it's used, for example,

```
data = FinancialData[#, "Price", {{2016}, {2020}, "Month"}, Method->"Legacy"][[All, 2]] & /@ Portfolio;
```

The `Method` option restores legacy output, i.e., real numbers and lists of date-value pairs, etc., in place of `Quantity` objects and `TimeSeries`.

If you prefer to update the old code to use the new features of `FinancialData`, use `QuantityMagnitude` to convert `Quantity` objects (such as currency values) to real numbers, and use the real number values wherever they're required. Here's how you might use the `Log` function ***without*** the `Method->"Legacy"` option:

```
dataValues = QuantityMagnitude[data];
Returns = Differences[Log[dataValues[[#]]]] & /@ Range[10];
```