# MATLAB to Mathematica CorrelationMatrix implementation

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, finance, matlab, correlation

This question focuses on translating/adapting custom defined MATLAB code for creating a CorrelationMatrix to Mathematica.

*Software and hardware used:*

- Mathematica Version 10.3.0.0
- Computer: Mac Pro (Late 2013)
- Processor: 3.5 GHz 6-Core Intel Xenon E5
- Memory: 32 GB 1866 MHzDDR3
- Graphics: AMD FirePro D500 3 GB

*Background*

I have begun the translation of a body of MATLAB code for [Pricing Bermudan Swaptions in the LIBOR Market Model](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:84440ee2-0284-4407-b1ed-07c2cf00e79b), from a dissertation by a Steffen Hippler.

From the paper's introduction:

> The fundamental entity modelled in the LIBOR market model is the
>   forward interest rate curve that specifies the simply compounded
>   interest rate at any two given points in time.
>
> ...
>
> Bermudan swaptions are interest rate derivatives with early exercise
>   features that are among the most liquidly traded (exotic) interest
>   rate derivative contracts.  Consequently, their pricing and risk
>   management is of high practical importance. The pricing of these
>   instruments, however, poses significant conceptual and theoretical
>   difficulties. This is due to the fact that, in general, the pricing
>   in the LIBOR market model has to be carried out via Monte Carlo
>   simulation techniques, which in turn do not lend themselves naturally
>   to the pricing of options with early exercise features.

I hope to eventually post a demonstration of the implementation on the Wolfram Demonstrations Project site.

Note: If `FinancialDerivate[]` or `CUDAFinancialDerivative[]` enabled such pricing, it would greatly simply my objective.

It does not appear that either function supports *Bermuda style options* (options that one can only exercise at defined times) or *swaptions*, options on swaps of fixed for floating cashflows.

A possible solution to this larger objective (which would likely require specialized knowledge outside the general domain of this forum), could show a way to utilize existing `FinancialDerivate[]` or `CUDAFinancialDerivative[]` functionality to replicate pricing of Bermuda Swaptions.

As I translate and develop the larger solution, I want to take advantage of Mathematica's functional approach as well as its high-level functionality.

*Background specific to the immediate question*

Hippler includes the following two custom MatLab functions for building a correlation matrix:

```
function [corr] = CorrFunc(beta, horizon, i, j)
    M=horizon;
    corr=exp(-abs(i-j)/(M-1)*(-log(beta(3))+beta(1)*(i^2+j^2+i*j-3*M*i-3*M*j+3*i+3*j+2*M^2-M-4)*1/((M-2)*(M-3))-beta(2)*(i^2+j^2+i*j-M*i-M*j+3*i+3*j+3*M^2-2)*1/((M-2)*(M-3))));
end

function CORR = CorrelationMatrix(beta, maturities, horizon, startRate, endRate)
   CORR=zeros(endRate-startRate);
   for i = startRate:endRate
        for j = startRate:endRate
            CORR(i,j) = CorrFunc(beta, horizon, maturities(j), maturities(i));
        end 
   end
end
```

Some definitions/term-examples:

**beta** (β or beta coefficient) - of an investment provides a measure of an instrument's volatility relative to a specific market as a whole.  An individual stock or bond may have more or less volatility than the the larger stock or bond markets.

**horizon** :

If you buy a zero-coupon bond and hold it to maturity, the ROR on your investment is the zero rate at which you bought the bond.

If you buy a t-year zero-coupon bond and sell it at time T

**maturities** - "maturity dates" on which the principal amount of the debt instruments become due and interest payments stop.

**startRate, endRate** - establishes a range of iteration.

The `CorrFunc` implements (in MATLAB) a parameterisation due to Schoenmakers and Coffey (J. Schoenmakers and C. Coffey, *[Systematic generation of parametric correlation structures for the libor market model](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219024903002055), International Journal of Theoretical and Applied Finance* (2002)) of the form:

$$\small \begin{align*}\rho_{ij}=\exp\left[-\frac{|i-j|}{M-1}\right.&\left(-\ln\beta_3+\beta_1\frac{i^2+j^2+ij-3Mi-3Mj+3i+3j+2M^2-M-4}{(M-2)(M-3)}\right.\\
&\left.\left.-\beta_2\frac{i^2+j^2+ij-Mi-Mj-3i-3j+3M^2-2}{(M-2)(M-3)}\right)\right]\end{align*}$$

with fitting parameter `β = (β1, β2, β3)` and `M` denoting the total number of rates under consideration.

I think, the MATLAB `CorrFunc` translates pretty directly to Mathematica:

```
corrFunc[beta_, horizon_, i_, j_] := Module[{M, corr},
  M = horizon;
  corr = Exp[-Abs[i - j]/(M - 1)*(-Log[beta[[3]]] + beta[[1]]*(i^2 + j^2 + i*j - 3*M*i - 3*M*j + 3*i + 3*j + 2*M^2 - M - 4)*1/((M - 2)*(M - 3)) - beta[[2]]*(i^2 + j^2 + i*j - M*i - M*j + 3*i + 3*j + 3*M^2 - 2)*1/((M - 2)*(M - 3)))]]
```

The MATLAB, `CorrelationMatrix` just looks like it simply applies the `CorrFunc` to a square matrix of the maturities.

So, it looks like I can simply do something like the following:

```
beta = {0.5, 0.4, 0.3};
horizon = 100;
Table[corrFunc[beta, horizon, i, j], {i, 10}, {j, 10}]
```

Note: I don't have MATLAB so I can't do a direct comparison of output.

Questions:

- Does it look like I'm on the right track?
- Whether, yes or no, can I alternatively do this by other/better means?
- `LinearModelFit`?
- `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`?
- Using `Listable` features?

As stated in the paper: The entire project of Pricing Bermudan Swaptions,

> ...poses significant conceptual and theoretical difficulties.

I want/hope to make use of all of Mathematica's advantages in simplifying code and writing efficient performing code.

It occurs to me that writing up the context of a question like this helps me, as an OP, better think about the problem.  Not that I have a solution, but I hope it gets me into the area of the solution.

Comment: How does one choose between two great answers?

Comment: Toss a coin. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was already a very good start. I take your function and modify it only slightly. I anticipate from the Matlab code that not the indices but the `maturities` should be arguments to `corrFunc`:

```
corrFunc[beta_, M_, mi_, mj_] := 
 Exp[-Abs[mi - mj]/(M - 1) (-Log[beta[[3]]] + 
     beta[[1]] (mi^2 + mj^2 + mi mj - 3 M mi - 3 M mj + 3 mi + 3 mj + 
        2 M^2 - M - 4) 1/((M - 2) (M - 3)) - 
     beta[[2]] (mi^2 + mj^2 + mi mj - M mi - M mj - 3 mi - 3 mj + 
        3 M^2 - 2) 1/((M - 2) (M - 3)))
  ]
```

Now we can loop directly over the list of `maturities`:

```
n = 100;
maturities = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
beta = {0.5, 0.4, 0.3};
horizon = 100;
data0 = Table[
    corrFunc[beta, horizon, mi, mj], 
    {mi, maturities}, 
    {mj, maturities}
]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.181448

In order to speed that up, I created a `CompiledFunction` with similar argument pattern. For performance reasons, I substitute the list `beta` by three scalar arguments. Moreover, I apply `N` to the body of the function to convert all constants to reals such that the eventual C code is free of type casts.

```
ccorrFunc = Block[{mi, mj, M, β1, β2, β3},
 With[{code = N@corrFunc[{β1, β2, β3}, M, mi, mj]},
   Compile[
    {{β1, _Real}, {β2, _Real}, {β3, _Real}, {M, _Real}, {mi, _Real}, {mj, _Real}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
  ]
 ]
```

This is how we employ this new function to compute the matrix.

```
{mi, mj} = Transpose@ Flatten[Outer[List, maturities, maturities, 1], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
data1 = Partition[
    ccorrFunc[Sequence @@ beta, horizon, mi, mj],
    n]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.00008
>
> 0.000518

This is about 300 times faster. And we obtain essentially the same result:

```
Max[Abs[data0 - data1]]
```

> 1.11022*10^-16

Since the input data is small compared to the actual computations, it might be also worthwhile to put that onto a graphics card. Unfortunately, my knowledge of OpenCL is a bit scarce... (CUDA would not work on the Fire Pro.)

**Edit**

Fixed signs in `corrFun` as suggested by J.M.

Comment: Henrik, I believe it should be `- 3 mi - 3 mj` in the polynomial multiplying `beta[[2]]`, if we go by the formula in the OP.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @J.M. , Henrik -- Comparing output of the current 3 versions on my 10.3.0.0 Mma installation: `data0` = Henrik's uncompiled version, `data1` = the compiled version, and `data2` =J.M.'s version with `Max[Abs[data0 - data1]]`, `Max[Abs[data1 - data2]]`, and `Max[Abs[data0 - data2]]` respectively gives me the following : 0.784386, 0.871319, 0.086933.  Thoughts?

Comment: That's odd, @Jagra. Letting `corrFunc[]` be Henrik's version, and `corrFuncNu[]` be my version, try this: `n = 100; BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; maturities = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]]; beta = {0.5, 0.4, 0.3}; horizon = 100; data0 = Table[corrFunc[beta, horizon, mi, mj], {mi, maturities}, {mj, maturities}];
data2 = DistanceMatrix[maturities, DistanceFunction -> Function[{mi, mj}, corrFuncNu[beta, horizon, mi, mj]]]; Max[Abs[data0 - data2]]` I find the result to be on the order of machine epsilon.

Comment: @J.M. - That did it.  I just overlooked setting the `SeedRandom` for both.  New difference: 1.11022*10^-16.  Too many late nights;-(

Comment: Henrik -- You get the win for the speed of your `CompiledFunction` solution.  I plan to adapt this for an OpenCL version and will post it when  I get it ready.  I do wish Wolfram would make CUDA work with FirePro/Mac.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to point out that Wolfram Research is hardly to blame for not supporting CUDA _on hardware that does not support CUDA_.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Henrik's implementation of `corrFunc[]`, I have managed to shorten it slightly (after correcting a sign mistake):

```
corrFuncNu[beta_, M_, mi_, mj_] := 
Exp[-Abs[mi - mj] (Take[beta, 2].((mi^2 + mi mj + mj^2) {1, -1} +
                   {3 (1 - M), M + 3} (mi + mj) +
                   {2 M^2 - M - 4, 2 - 3 M^2})/((M - 2) (M - 3)) - Log[beta[[3]]])/(M - 1)]
```

We can then use `DistanceMatrix[]` with a custom distance function to generate the matrix:

```
n = 100;
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; maturities = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]];
beta = {0.5, 0.4, 0.3}; horizon = 100;

DistanceMatrix[maturities, DistanceFunction -> Function[{mi, mj},
                           corrFuncNu[beta, horizon, mi, mj]]]
```

(in older versions, replace `corrFuncNu[beta, horizon, mi, mj]` with `corrFuncNu[beta, horizon, First[mi], First[mj]]`)

On the computer I am using, this is twice as fast as generating the matrix with `Table[]`, and just as accurate.

Comment: @Jagra, thanks; I forgot that I changed the name of the function I modified. :)

Comment: My pleasure.  Any reason not to follow Henrik's idea and compile what you've written?

Comment: Well, `corrFuncNu[]` can certainly be compiled, but `DistanceMatrix[]` cannot.

Comment: I just ran Absolute timing on your version: 3.*10^-6 and Henrik's: 4.*10^-6 .  Wow.

Comment: J.M., the `First` calls lead to errors since their arguments are scalars. Removing them works, leads to a correct result but needs about `0.1` seconds for `n = 100` on my machine. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jagra I think something went wrong on your machine; these timings indicate that nothing happened.

Comment: @Henrik, I had tested it on 10.4, which needs the preprocessing with `First[]`. You are right that in 11.2, the `First[]` is unnecessary. I'll add a note.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - Ah, it appears the machine worked fine, but my late night removing of `// AbsoluteTiming // First` from one line and adding of `%// AbsoluteTiming // First` below it produced "Wow" results.

Comment: Yeah, these things happen at night... =D