# Retrieving forthcoming step size from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, random

I'm solving a system of ODEs with a random component, which changes at each calculation step and depends on the step size. So I'm trying to realize something like this: (1) size of the forthcoming step is retrieved from NDSolve (2) random component is calculated (3) only then the step is evaluated with a corresponding random component. Unfortunately, I don't know how to squeeze between the moment, when NDSolve selects step size and when it evaluates the step. StepMonitor (*commented in the code*) doesn't allow that, as I understand, since it returns information after the step is evaluated.

ps1 Fixed step method is 5x longer, which means hours of difference, since I need 10^5-10^6 evaluations for a single final plot, so this would be a really undesirable option.

ps2 Using previous step size also doesn't seem good due to abrupt changes at some points

Here is the code:

```
Remove["Global`*"]

(* PARAMETERS *)
γ = 
 1.76*10.^7*10.^4 (*T^-1s^-1*);    α = 0.06;   θsh = \
0.3;   Ms = 7.*10.^5; (*A/m*)   tFM = 2.*10.^-9; (*m*)
currAMP = 30.*10.^-3 (*A*);   sHM = 
 10.*10.^-6*3.*10.^-9(* m^2, tHM = 3 nm *);
Hamp = 0.03; Hk = 0.1;
a = 0. °; b = 0. °; c = 0. °; Ang = 
 0. °; 
temp = 3; rad = 20.*10.^-9; (*Thermal effect*)
kTL = 2.;
tSt = 0.;  tFin = 1.5*10.0^-8;  tStep = 1.*10.0^-12;

(* CURRENT PULSE *)
tPulse = 5.*10^-9; tRise = 0.5*10^-9;
jcurr[t_] := Piecewise[{{1., -1 <= t <= tPulse}}, 0.];
Cjconst = (3.29375`*^-16) (θsh/Ms/tFM)*currAMP/sHM;
Cj[t_] := Cj[t] = jcurr[t]*Cjconst;

(* FIELD COMPONENTS *)
σf[temp_, rad_] := Sqrt[(
 2.*α*1.38*10.^-23*temp)/(γ*Ms*tFM*3.1415*rad^2*
  tStep)];  σ = σf[temp, rad];  (*stand.dev*)
RandComp[] := 
 RandomVariate[
  NormalDistribution[0., σ]]/Sqrt[3.]; (*random component*)
Happ = ({
    {Cos[c], -Sin[c], 0.},
    {Sin[c], Cos[c], 0.},
    {0., 0., 1.}
   }).({
    {Cos[b], 0., Sin[b]},
    {0., 1., 0.},
    {-Sin[b], 0., Cos[b]}
   }).({
    {1., 0., 0.},
    {0., Cos[a], -Sin[a]},
    {0., Sin[a], Cos[a]}
   }).( {
    {Hamp*Cos[Ang]},
    {Hamp*(-Sin[Ang])},
    {0.}
   }); (*permanent applied component*)
Hrand[t_] := Hrand[t] = {RandComp[], RandComp[], RandComp[]};
H[t_, mz_] := Flatten[Happ + Hrand[t] + {0., -kTL*Cj[t], Hk*mz}]

(* ODE SYSTEM *)
t0 = 0;
NDSolve[( {
   {mX'[t] == γ (-mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] + 
        mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[
          2]] - α (mY[
             t] (mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] - mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]]) - 
           mZ[t] (mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] - mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]])) + 
        Cj[t]*mY[t]*mX[t] + α*Cj[t]*mZ[t]), mX[0] == 0.},
   {mY'[t] == γ (-mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] + 
        mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[
          3]] - α (mZ[
             t] (mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] - mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]]) - 
           mX[t] (mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] - mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]])) - 
        Cj[t] (mX[t]^2 + mZ[t]^2)), mY[0] == 0.},
   {mZ'[t] == γ (-mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] + 
        mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[
          1]] - α (mX[
             t] (mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] - mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]]) - 
           mY[t] (mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] - mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]])) + 
        Cj[t]*mY[t]*mZ[t] - α*Cj[t]*mX[t]), mZ[0] == 1.}
  } ), {mX, mY, mZ}, {t, tSt, tFin}, StartingStepSize -> 10.^-16, 
 Method -> {"Projection", Method -> "Automatic", 
   "Invariants" -> (mX[t]^2 + mY[t]^2 + mZ[t]^2 == 1)}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 10000 (*,StepMonitor:>Block[{},
 δt=t-t0;t0=t;
 Print["Current time: ",t];
 Print["Current step: ",δt];
 Print["mX: ",mX[t]];
 Print["mY: ",mY[t]];
 Print["mZ: ",mZ[t],"
 "];
 AbsoluteTiming[Pause[1]]
 ]*)
 ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at the implementation of `MonitorMethod` [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html).

Comment: Despite the fact that this is an interesting question, there is a reason why most people use a fixed time step Heun scheme in LLG. So before wasting your time, have a look at [this](http://www.fgarciasanchez.es/thesisfelipe/node20.html) and the references therein.

Comment: Moreover, in a variable time step method you need to decide which step to take. This is usually done by comparing one step with $t$ to two steps with $t/2$. As you have a stochastic component you cannot compare the two endpoints. From this point of view I am surprised that this works in Mathematica. Are you sure that the stochastic field is really generated for every step?

Comment: @mikuszefski, so, to determine standard deviation, size step is required and to select the size step, stochastic component (i.e. standard deviation) should be fixed. So it's a vicious circle. Thank you for that insight and for the reference. Seems like I have to stick to fixed step method.

Comment: @mikuszefski As for the stochastic field generation, I use memoization for that, so it should be calculated once and then kept for all calculations on that step, until the time _t_ is changed. At least, multiple trials' results are different, so I believe it works.

Comment: Concerning memorization, this is good to ensure that the value does not vary upon one step $t$. Note that you will also get the same values in consecutive simulations assuming you hit the same $t$'s, which I am not sure about. My question is the following (as I cannot test your code at the moment): Do you see noise on the result? Does it change if you change the temperature (independent of the question if the result is correct with respect to the time step)?

Comment: Though the result varies from trial to trial, something is wrong with the noise indeed: (T = 300 K, m0*Hk = 0.1 T) 
[Methods comparison](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/3928/nIk3pC.png).
Right-hand side image was calculated with classical Runge-Kutta, which I wrote with a For loop, so it executes really slowly, but seems most reliable among these three.

Comment: @mikuszefski you was right about the stochastic field, it's generated just ones in the beginning indeed. The reason is that NDSolve calls function `Hrand[t]` (which generates random field) with time variable _t_ instead of its certain value.
I tried creating an array of pre-generated stochastic fields first and then address its elements, but encountered the same problem: NDSolve sends symbolic _t_, which provokes "the expression ... cannot be a part of specification" error.
Is there a way around it? How to make NDSolve send actual value of _t_?

Comment: Well, try to have a look at some [old threads](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/how-can-you-compute-it%C5%8D-integrals-with-mathematica), at the [documentation center](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StochasticDifferentialEquationProcesses.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ideal electromagnetic switch-on-process in a real electromagnetic cable.

It seems that the modeling of the step input for the current is rather not physical. The invariant is delayed perturbed in a non-neglectable manner.

First, take into account that NDSolve is proven in practice and not a built-in that is made for step size control. That was a wish by the Mathematica customers and a consequence of the test suits on which it is verified for the highest possible versatility. It saves time and effort for the users.

There are still of course workarounds to control [step size](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html) for tedious and error-prone partial differential equations. This case is not close to such problems.

I did put the precision options out of the command. Automatic means for the Projection option too the use of [`Runge-Kutta`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html). A proper choice for it is to match the order of the coefficients favored. So with `Automatic` these whole lot of optimization are done by Mathematica in NDSolve for the best solution.

With this in mind the results for

```
Remove["Global`*"]

(*PARAMETERS*)
γ = 
 1.76*10.^7*10.^4 (*T^-1s^-1*); α = 0.06; θsh = 0.3; Ms \
= 7.*10.^5;(*A/m*)tFM = 2.*10.^-9;(*m*)currAMP = 
 30.*10.^-3 (*A*); sHM = 10.*10.^-6*3.*10.^-9(*m^2,tHM=3 nm*);
Hamp = 0.03; Hk = 0.1;
a = 0. °; b = 0. °; c = 0. °; Ang = 
 0. °;
temp = 3; rad = 20.*10.^-9;(*Thermal effect*)kTL = 2.;
tSt = 0.; tFin = 1.5*10.0^-8; tStep = 1.*10.0^-12;

(*CURRENT PULSE*)
tPulse = 5.*10^-9; tRise = 0.5*10^-9;
jcurr[t_] := Piecewise[{{1., -1 <= t <= tPulse}}, 0.];
Cjconst = (3.29375`*^-16) (θsh/Ms/tFM)*currAMP/sHM;
Cj[t_] := Cj[t] = jcurr[t]*Cjconst;

(*FIELD COMPONENTS*)
σf[temp_, rad_] := 
 Sqrt[(2.*α*1.38*10.^-23*temp)/(γ*Ms*tFM*3.1415*rad^2*
     tStep)]; σ = σf[temp, rad];(*stand.dev*)
RandComp[] := 
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., σ]]/
  Sqrt[3.];(*random component*)Happ = ({{Cos[c], -Sin[c], 
     0.}, {Sin[c], Cos[c], 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}}).({{Cos[b], 0., 
     Sin[b]}, {0., 1., 0.}, {-Sin[b], 0., Cos[b]}}).({{1., 0., 
     0.}, {0., Cos[a], -Sin[a]}, {0., Sin[a], 
     Cos[a]}}).({{Hamp*
      Cos[Ang]}, {Hamp*(-Sin[
         Ang])}, {0.}});(*permanent applied component*)
Hrand[t_] := Hrand[t] = {RandComp[], RandComp[], RandComp[]};
H[t_, mz_] := Flatten[Happ + Hrand[t] + {0., -kTL*Cj[t], Hk*mz}]

(*ODE SYSTEM*)
t0 = 0;
sol = NDSolve[({{mX'[
       t] == γ (-mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] + 
         mZ[t]*H[t, 
            mZ[t]][[2]] - α (mY[
              t] (mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] - mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]]) - 
            mZ[t] (mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] - mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]])) +
          Cj[t]*mY[t]*mX[t] + α*Cj[t]*mZ[t]), 
     mX[0] == 
      0.}, {mY'[
       t] == γ (-mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] + 
         mX[t]*H[t, 
            mZ[t]][[3]] - α (mZ[
              t] (mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] - mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]]) - 
            mX[t] (mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] - mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]])) -
          Cj[t] (mX[t]^2 + mZ[t]^2)), 
     mY[0] == 
      0.}, {mZ'[
       t] == γ (-mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] + 
         mY[t]*H[t, 
            mZ[t]][[1]] - α (mX[
              t] (mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] - mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]]) - 
            mY[t] (mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] - mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]])) +
          Cj[t]*mY[t]*mZ[t] - α*Cj[t]*mX[t]), 
     mZ[0] == 1.}}), {mX, mY, mZ}, {t, tSt, tFin}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 1, 
  Method -> {"Projection", Method -> "Automatic", 
    "Invariants" -> (mX[t]^2 + mY[t]^2 + mZ[t]^2 == 1)}(*,
  StepMonitor\[RuleDelayed]Block[{},δt=t-t0;t0=t;
  Print["Current time: ",t];
  Print["Current step: ",δt];
  Print["mX: ",mX[t]];
  Print["mY: ",mY[t]];
  Print["mZ: ",mZ[t],"
   "];
  AbsoluteTiming[Pause[1]]]*)]
```

are

[image: InterpolationFunction]

[image: Graphics]

The peak at the delayed time t about `5.5 ns` for the invariant is a violation of the foundational physics for the problem. Since the problem is reduced from the mathematical standpoint this is the solution.

The best path for a more physical solution will be to model that the peak does not appear. For example model some counter current from the other side of the electric system or some immanent current sources that delay in the calculated or near calculated manner.

Another interpretation might be, that there are times of unphysical solutions unavoidable in this modeling. Another one is a sign is set wrong. Nevertheless, the system recovers.

```
Remove["Global`*"]

(*PARAMETERS*)
γ = 
 1.76*10.^7*10.^4 (*T^-1s^-1*); α = 0.06; θsh = 0.3; Ms \
= 7.*10.^5;(*A/m*)tFM = 2.*10.^-9;(*m*)currAMP = 
 30.*10.^-3 (*A*); sHM = 10.*10.^-6*3.*10.^-9(*m^2,tHM=3 nm*);
Hamp = 0.03; Hk = 0.1;
a = 0. °; b = 0. °; c = 0. °; Ang = 
 0. °;
temp = 3; rad = 20.*10.^-9;(*Thermal effect*)kTL = 2.;
tSt = 0.; tFin = 1.5*10.0^-8; tStep = 1.*10.0^-12;

(*CURRENT PULSE*)
tPulse = 5.*10^-9; tRise = 0.5*10^-9;
jcurr[t_] := Piecewise[{{1., -1 <= t <= tPulse}}, 0.];
Cjconst = (3.29375`*^-16) (θsh/Ms/tFM)*currAMP/sHM;
Cj[t_] := Cj[t] = jcurr[t]*Cjconst;

(*FIELD COMPONENTS*)
σf[temp_, rad_] := 
 Sqrt[(2.*α*1.38*10.^-23*temp)/(γ*Ms*tFM*3.1415*rad^2*
     tStep)]; σ = σf[temp, rad];(*stand.dev*)
RandComp[] := 
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., σ]]/
  Sqrt[3.];(*random component*)Happ = ({{Cos[c], -Sin[c], 
     0.}, {Sin[c], Cos[c], 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}}).({{Cos[b], 0., 
     Sin[b]}, {0., 1., 0.}, {-Sin[b], 0., Cos[b]}}).({{1., 0., 
     0.}, {0., Cos[a], -Sin[a]}, {0., Sin[a], 
     Cos[a]}}).({{Hamp*
      Cos[Ang]}, {Hamp*(-Sin[
         Ang])}, {0.}});(*permanent applied component*)
Hrand[t_] := Hrand[t] = {RandComp[], RandComp[], RandComp[]};
H[t_, mz_] := Flatten[Happ + Hrand[t] + {0., -kTL*Cj[t], Hk*mz}]

(*ODE SYSTEM*)
t0 = 0;
sol0 = NDSolve[({{mX'[
       t] == γ (-mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] + 
         mZ[t]*H[t, 
            mZ[t]][[2]] - α (mY[
              t] (mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] - mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]]) - 
            mZ[t] (mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] - mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]])) +
          Cj[t]*mY[t]*mX[t] + α*Cj[t]*mZ[t]), 
     mX[0] == 
      0.}, {mY'[
       t] == γ (-mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] + 
         mX[t]*H[t, 
            mZ[t]][[3]] - α (mZ[
              t] (mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] - mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]]) - 
            mX[t] (mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] - mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]])) -
          Cj[t] (mX[t]^2 + mZ[t]^2)), 
     mY[0] == 
      0.}, {mZ'[
       t] == γ (-mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] + 
         mY[t]*H[t, 
            mZ[t]][[1]] - α (mX[
              t] (mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] - mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]]) - 
            mY[t] (mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] - mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]])) +
          Cj[t]*mY[t]*mZ[t] - α*Cj[t]*mX[t]), 
     mZ[0] == 1.}}), {mX, mY, mZ}, {t, tSt, tFin}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 10.^-16, 
  Method -> {"Projection", Method -> "Automatic", 
    "Invariants" -> (mX[t]^2 + mY[t]^2 + mZ[t]^2 == 1)}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 10000]
StepDataPlot[sol0, PlotRange -> {tSt, tFin}]
Plot[{mX[t], mY[t], mZ[t], mX[t]^2 + mY[t]^2 + mZ[t]^2} /. sol0, {t, 
  tSt, tFin}]
```

[image: Output]

[image: Output]

Great! Many thanks.

A look into the methods with the implementation from [NDSolvePlugIns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html):

```
(*ODE SYSTEM*)
t0 = 0;
methodstep = 
 NDSolve[({{mX'[
       t] == \[Gamma] (-mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] + 
         mZ[t]*H[t, 
            mZ[t]][[2]] - \[Alpha] (mY[
              t] (mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] - mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]]) - 
            mZ[t] (mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] - mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]])) +
          Cj[t]*mY[t]*mX[t] + \[Alpha]*Cj[t]*mZ[t]), 
     mX[0] == 
      0.}, {mY'[
       t] == \[Gamma] (-mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] + 
         mX[t]*H[t, 
            mZ[t]][[3]] - \[Alpha] (mZ[
              t] (mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] - mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]]) - 
            mX[t] (mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] - mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]])) -
          Cj[t] (mX[t]^2 + mZ[t]^2)), 
     mY[0] == 
      0.}, {mZ'[
       t] == \[Gamma] (-mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]] + 
         mY[t]*H[t, 
            mZ[t]][[1]] - \[Alpha] (mX[
              t] (mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[1]] - mX[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]]) - 
            mY[t] (mY[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[3]] - mZ[t]*H[t, mZ[t]][[2]])) +
          Cj[t]*mY[t]*mZ[t] - \[Alpha]*Cj[t]*mX[t]), 
     mZ[0] == 1.}}), {mX, mY, mZ}, {t, tSt, tFin}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 10.^-16, 
  Method -> {"Projection", Method -> MonitorMethod, 
    "Invariants" -> (mX[t]^2 + mY[t]^2 + mZ[t]^2 == 1)}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 10000 (*,
  StepMonitor\[RuleDelayed]Block[{},\[Delta]t=t-t0;t0=t;
  Print["Current time: ",t];
  Print["Current step: ",\[Delta]t];
  Print["mX: ",mX[t]];
  Print["mY: ",mY[t]];
  Print["mZ: ",mZ[t],"
   "];
  AbsoluteTiming[Pause[1]]]*)]
```

[image: out of MethodMonitor]

This shows that the `DifferenceOrder` is rapidly increase and not released to the order of `16`. It shows that the Stepsize is decrease even faster and never decreaser below $10^{-15}$.

[image]

Values are not constant at the end of the chosen time interval.

data2a = Transpose[{autostep[[1, 1, 2]]["Coordinates"][[1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html)],
autostep[[1, 1, 2]]["ValuesOnGrid"]}];
Show[Plot[autostep[[1, 1, 2]][t], {t, 0, 1.5 10^-8},
PlotRange -> All],
ListPlot[data2a, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All],
ImageSize -> 500]

[image: to what is done by NDSolve]

```
data2a = Transpose[{autostep[[1, 2, 2]]["Coordinates"][[1]], 
    autostep[[1, 2, 2]]["ValuesOnGrid"]}];
Show[Plot[autostep[[1, 2, 2]][t], {t, 0, 1.5 10^-8}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[data2a, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: to what is done by NDSolve]

```
data3a = Transpose[{autostep[[1, 3, 2]]["Coordinates"][[1]], 
    autostep[[1, 3, 2]]["ValuesOnGrid"]}];
Show[Plot[autostep[[1, 3, 2]][t], {t, 0, 1.5 10^-8}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[data3a, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: to what is done by NDSolve]

This remains looking artificial. This compare "Coordinates" to "ValueOnGrid". The patterns are synchronized but the pattern seems strangely sparse where the interesting integration occurs. This is the  [ploterror](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html)  function rewritten for the presented code.

This paper [Fundamental Limits to Moore's Law](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05956.pdf) discusses the question from the information thermodynamic perspective and offers rather shorter times. The Shannon-von Neumann-Landauer (SNL) expression together with the  Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle gives as time uncertainty:

$$ 0.04 ps $$

In their chapter 5:
"5. Practical aspects
Power consumption and speed are limited
fundamentally by the devices, but practically by the
electrical parasites, interconnects and chip
architecture. This is the reason for the clock speed to
have saturated at about 3 GHz for today's processors.
All alternative ideas, like optical interconnects and
more would see their limit in the domain conversion,
which is limited by thermodynamics discussed here.
The "2" in kBT ln2 can be made higher to, say, m, but
that only pushes the limits by a factor of ln(m)/ln2.
[7-8]"

This is a reference to general scientific results: [Quantum physics sets a speed limit to electronics.](https://phys.org/news/2022-03-quantum-physics-limit-electronics.html)

Comment: Impressive, timeless.